# VSCode shortcut to select menu in Linux

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code

Iʼm running VSCode on Linux. Its window contains menu bar (usual style: File, Edit, ..., Help) which is accessible only with the mouse. I havenʼt managed to find a shortcut to select a menu item or even the whole menu bar. This differs from Windows where this menu is controllable using regular Windows style (Alt+F for File, etc.)

Is there a shortcut to go to the menu bar or its item? What is its name, if present?

Linux = Ubuntu 20.04+KDE, freshly updated.
VSCode = 1.68.1 (latest today) from Ubuntu snap (stable channel).

Comment: It works with the `alt` key, but is flaky and gets stuck sometimes and won't display the menu at all that way since `alt + leftbuttondown` is window move on most Linux desktops. I remapped as `{ "key": "alt+m", "command": "workbench.action.toggleMenuBar" }` and that worked fine.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Toggling menu bar doesn't help in activating it. Single Alt doesn't ever work in my case.

Answer (score 0):

It works well for me (Ubuntu: 20.04.4 LTS, VSCode: 1.68.0) and it is supposed to work in the same way for Linux or Windows. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_keyboard_shortcuts.

What happen when you press Alt? Can it select the menu bar?

Comment: Pressing Alt does nothing in VSCode, nor it selects menu in any other application with menu. But, for example, in Firefox Alt+F selects File menu in it, unlike VSCode.